# Ansible playbook complains about quotes

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I'm using Ubuntu 16 with Ansible 2.2.1.0.

I am trying to install `docker-compose` with the following playbook:

```
  - name: Install Docker Compose.
      shell: "curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
      file:
         dest=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose mode=x
         src=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose  dest=/usr/bin/docker-compose state=link
```

I get this error:

```
  - name: Install Docker Compose.
      shell: "curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
           ^ here
This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.  For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'
```

What is the problem? I have starting and ending quotes.

Comment: Shell is a built in ansible modules. All modules syntactically have to aligned exactly below the name. It’s nothing to do with ansible, YAML thingy. They are “quotes” not quotas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shell module hasn't file parameter and shell and name should be on same column that why you got the error and also use a double quote for URL and not full shell command:

```
   - name: Install Docker Compose.
     shell: curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
```

You can use the [get_url](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html) module to download the file to the destination and set permission. And I highly recommend using Ansible role that presented by contributors on the [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) and not to reinvited wheels!